# Determine if application is running in KIOSK Mode dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, kiosk-mode

I have a web based application which runs using IE browser on Windows Operating System. I need to perform special logic when a computer/laptop/PC is running in KIOSK mode.

I am wondering is there any way we can determine Programmatically /dynamically using c#, if a computer/laptop/PC is running  in KIOSK mode.

Comment: Is this with Silverlight, or an ASP.NET web site, or something else?

Comment: It's ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: You could setup pseudo-login functionality and define a RoleProvider with a role called something like "kioskUser". Then in every controller you could run your custom logic for kiosk users only.

Comment: @Shoe -- I am not able to understand what 'pseudo-login functionality'  means  ?? We don't have any login functionality/screen to perform. Actual functionality is as soon as application launches, it will take the user directly in to home page.

Comment: I mean to say that if the application is meant to run for long periods of time, then you could setup a simplemembership and roleprovider with a "kioskUser". You could have a button that changes the app from regular to kiosk mode and when you deploy it on the kiosk click the button. In this way you mock a login system without an actual login